# how can I write an address in a register?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, addressing-mode

```
DOSSEG
.MODEL SMALL

.STACK

.DATA

    PUBLIC  SECTOR
SECTOR  DB  'R', 'o', 'b', 'e', 'r', 't', 'o', '$'


.CODE

    EXTRN   WRITE_CHAR:PROC

INDEX PROC

    ; ==================================== 1)
    MOV     AX, DGROUP
    MOV     DS, AX                  
    XOR     BX, BX
    MOV     CX, 7
L1:
    MOV     DL, SECTOR[BX]
    CALL    WRITE_CHAR
    INC     BX
    LOOP    L1
    
    ; ==================================== 2) 
    MOV     AH, 09h
    MOV     DX, 000Ah
    INT     21h
            
    MOV     AH, 4Ch
    INT     21h
    RET
INDEX ENDP

    
    END INDEX
```

This assembly code manages to print a string using the "relative base" system (see comment code 1).
This code works correctly.

Now I know that the function 09h in AH, using INT 21h, allows me to display all the characters of a string located in memory, until the character $ is reached (see comment code 2).
I directly put the offset address in DX (MOV DX, 000Ah) of the memory location where the first character of the string that I want to print resides.

I would like to understand how I can insert this address, fetching it from SECTOR [0] or simply SECTOR, since this points to the first element of the string in that memory area.

I tried, but without success, using this instruction:
MOV DX, Word ptr SECTOR

Note: The WRITE_CHAR procedure is simply a piece of code that prints me a character starting from its ASCII code.
If necessary, I can also report that code, but it doesn't seem necessary for the problem I have.

Comment: `MOV DX, OFFSET SECTOR` ?

Comment: YES ... this is the correct instruction to write that address in the DX register. Could you put it as a definitive answer? In the Wikipedia explanation about OFFSET I found the definition, now everything is clear. Thanks again.

Comment: It's not a standardized notation, some assemblers want you to put `offset` in front and others do it automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MOV DX, Word ptr SECTOR` reads the first word located at `SECTOR` and places the value in `DX`. All `Word ptr` does is tell the assembler that you want to read a word (which in this case should be redundant, since the destination operand has a known size).

What you're looking for is the `OFFSET` operator; as in:

`MOV DX, OFFSET SECTOR`